# How to address positions of marks from simple matrix data in the boxes between axis lines?

Tags: matlab, plot

What is the simplest way to create the following plot in Matlab from the data of the matrix "positions" containing the value 1 for black marks and - 1 for white marks?

```
positions=[0 1 0 0 0 0; 0 -1 0 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0 0 0; 1 -1 1 1 -1 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
% //Data
positions = [0 1 0 0 0 0; 0 -1 0 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0 0 0; 1 -1 1 1 -1 0];
S = 50; %// circle size. Adjust manually

%// Preparation
[M N] = size(positions);
hold on

%// Plot filled circles
[ip jp] = find(flipud(positions)>0);
plot(jp-.5,ip-.5,'ko','markersize',S,'markerfacecolor','k')

%// Plot empty circles
[in jn] = find(flipud(positions)<0);
plot(jn-.5,in-.5,'ko','markersize',S)

%// Plot grid lines
plot([0 N],(1:M).'*[1 1],'k');
plot((1:N).'*[1 1],[0 M],'k');

%// Set tick labels
set(gca,'xtick',.5:N,'ytick',.5:M)
set(gca,'xticklabel',char((1:N).'+'A'-1),'yticklabel',char((1:M).'+'0'))

%// Set axis size and aspect
axis equal
axis([0 N 0 M])
set(gca,'ticklength',[0 0]) %// no visible ticks
```

[image]